# HTTP 403 error when enabling query logging in SharePoint 2007

Tags: search, administration, permissions

When attempting to enable search query logging from the Shared Services Provider of my SharePoint 2007 farm, IIS returns the HTTP 403 error page. My account has full-control rights at the farm and site-collection levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you have to add your account to the SSP access list.

More details can be found at:

http://www.sharepointassist.com/2009/01/07/error-enabling-enable-advanced-usage-analysis-processing-on-spusageconfigaspx/